# How does H2O weigh base learners when stacking ensemble is applied?

Tags: python, h2o, ensemble-learning

How does H2O determine the weights for base learners? For exp. here in the [example](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html), are all the base learners equally weighted? And do I have a chance to use regularization parameters (e.g. ridge) in metalearner_algorithm? What would be the best way to avoid overfitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea of stacked ensemble (and the thing that differentiates it from other types of ensemble, such as random forest, GBMs, [simple averaging of confidences](http://darrendev.blogspot.co.uk/2016/10/multinomial-ensemble-in-h2o.html)) is that it uses another machine learning model to determine how to weight the base learners. (This other model is the meta-learner.)

For your second question, you currently cannot specify any parameters, but there is [a ticket for it](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5086), so there is a fair chance it will be available in the next few months.

In the meantime, I would say paying attention to over-fitting in the base models, is more important than regularization in the meta-learner.

Comment: Are over-fit base models good or bad when ensemble modelling?

Comment: @Brad That is an interesting question. In my answer above I meant "avoid over-fitting in the base models, it is bad". But you could imagine a situation where the meta-learner could learn that a base model has (slightly) over-fitted and work with that to give a slightly better ensemble.

Comment: Thanks. I fit my base learners using carets selectionFunction = tolerance. Then combine the models using only the probability columns by penalized logistic regression with all interactive terms. Using 1 training set, and 1 meta-training set and 1 holdout set. The bias that concerns me is my human brain as I see what happens in the holdout set, then I go back and change feature section and fit selection criteria (one SE, tolerance, etc). The bias is not present in the code. I really need 2-holdout sets to mitigate this bias. The 2nd holdout set allowing only 1 single attempt.

Comment: Another thing I learnt by ensemble modelling is sometimes more base learners can be good even if returns are diminishing they can offer something. For example if the meta-training set is only 100 rows. 2 base learners would give 200 data points - But 5 base learners gives 500 data points. Thereby stabilizing logistic regression even in data limited situations.